# Can't override _renderItem function in jQuery UI autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to display images with labels in jQuery UI Autocomplete.

I got stuck at the error

> jquery-ui.js:6853 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined".

However, during my investigation, it turned out that the problem is in overriding `_renderItem` function - whatever I do in its overridden implementation, I see the same error, even if I define it by just copying code from jQuery UI source code.

I tried jQuery UI versions 1.10.4 1.11.4 and 1.10.2 and the problem still exists.

I think that I've already tried almost everything, even making really silly versions of autocomplete, but still, every time I do something with `_renderItem` implementation, the error occurs.

According to the source code of jQuery UI, the reason for this error is a lack of `ui-autocomplete-item` data, but I do send it, so I've got no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

this is for jQuery 1.10.2

```
   var autoComObj = $("#id").autocomplete({
                minLength : 3,
                width : 590,
                scroll : true,
                scrollHeight : 250,
                matchContains : true,
                autoFill : false,
                cacheLength : 1,
                source:function(request,response){//some code },
                select:function(event,ui){//selection code }
                });
    autoComObj.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem=function(ul, item){//custom renderItem code. }
```

Comment: The problem still exists, even with something exactly like:
`$( "#automplete-1" ).autocomplete({
                    source: ["a", "b", "c"]
             })
                     .data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                  return $( "<li>" )
                            .data( "ui-autocomplete-item", item )
                            .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
                            .appendTo( ul );
         };`